# How can I add a QPushButton to QTabWidget header?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8, qpushbutton

I created tab with:

```
ui->tabWidget->addTab(widgetTab,"Title");
```

I want to add a refresh button after tab text "Title". How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can directly. The `QTabBar` element of `QTabWidget` is only accessible via the `tabBar()` member function, which is protected. And `QTabBar`'s `setTabButton` isn't exposed otherwise in the tab widget's interface.

You could do it by subclassing `QTabWidget` though. Something like:

```
class MyTabWidget: public QTabWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MyTabWidget(QWidget *parent = 0)
            : QTabWidget(parent)
        {
            addTab(new QLabel("foo"), "foo");
            addTab(new QLabel("bar"), "bar");
            QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton("<");
            QPushButton *b2 = new QPushButton(">");
            tabBar()->setTabButton(0, QTabBar::LeftSide, b1);
            tabBar()->setTabButton(1, QTabBar::RightSide, b2);
        }
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have some problems: I created a class which name is myTabWidget and I used your code. I wrote "MyTabWidget *mytab=new MyTabWidget(); ui->tabWidget->addTab(mytab,"my tab");" This created 2 tabs one inside other. Header of outer is "my tab" and header of inner is "foo". Second one is what I want to do. But how can I get rid of outer tab? or How should I use your code?

Comment: You need to change your ui class to use `MyTabWidget` instead of `QTabWidget`.

Comment: I changed my class. I created a function "createNewTab()". When I call it, only first tab is created with QPushButton. There is no button other tabs. I created an object first: MyTabWidget *tw=new MyTabWidget(); then I call my function: tw->createNewTab();

Comment: Then there's a bug somewhere in your code, probably in the createNewTab function. Look at it carefully, keeping in mind you need a new push button for each new tab. If you can't figure it out, open a new question.

Comment: OK I solved. setTabButton function needs index parameter and this is always 0 in my function. This is why it adds QPushButton only first tab. I changed your code as follows: int index=addTab(new QLabel("foo"), "foo"); QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton("<"); tabBar()->setTabButton(index, QTabBar::LeftSide, b1); Thank you @Mat